# How can I cut these intersecting faces off?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

Modelling a house to be used as an in-game asset. Created a clapboard wall using an array and solidify modifier and was left with with some intersecting faces [image]

At first I tried using a boolean modifier and also swapped the positions of the array and solidify modifier around. This is the result of the boolean modifier [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to keep the planks complete and not cut them off in the middle, the intersecting object has to contain the plank object completely, i.e. you have to scale the object "Main House" a little larger so that "Main House.001" is completely inside of it. You can either *Scale* "Main House" with the <kbd>S</kbd> key or better do it this way:

1. Select "Main House" (the "clean" house without clapboard planks) and in *Edit Mode* use *Shrink/Fatten* with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to increase the size (maybe hit <kbd>S</kbd> again for *Even Offset*).

[image: shrink/fatten]

2. Make it big enough to completely hide the clapboard planks, but do not exceed the roof. Then left-click or <kbd>Return</kbd> to confirm the action.

[image: hide planks]

3. Now back in *Object Mode*, select your object "Main House.001" (with the clapboard planks), set the *Boolean Modifier* to *Intersect*, choose the "clean" house "Main House" as *Object* to intersect those parts.

[image: intersect]

4. Now to really see the result you have to hide the surrounding object "Main House". To do that, you have to hide it in the *Viewport* (the eye symbol in the *Outliner*) and very important, to avoid unwanted surprises: *Disable in Render* (the camera symbol in the *Outliner*).

[image: hide object]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This method wouldnt be useful in my case as the house isnt being used for a render but as an in game object meaning the viewport method wouldnt work

Comment: Of course this method works. You can't use it with the boolean modifier in other game engines anyway. You have to apply the modifier to create the object "for real", then you can delete the surrounding house as it is only needed for a non-destructive method - like keeping the boolean modifier - and in this case it would be in the way in the viewport and render. Once the object is finally created you don't have to care for the rest. You asked the question as if the result as shown wasn't what you expected it to be.